# Convolution of identical density functions

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

Let $X,Y$ be random variables each with density $f(x)=2xI_{x
∈[0,1]}$ , where $I_{A}$ is the indicator function on the event $A$. What is the density of the random variable $U:=X+Y$?

I start by using convolutions, the density of $U$:

\begin{aligned}
  f_U (u)=(f*f)(u)
   &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)f(u-x)\,dx \\
   &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}4x(u-x)I_{x∈[0,1]}I_{u-x∈[0,1]}\,dx\\
\end{aligned}

However, I am struggling to proceed. I assume the indicators change the limits of integration, is this correct? If so does the expression become
$$\int_{0}^{1}4x(u-x)I_{u-x∈[0,1]}\,dx$$
Any ideas on how I deal with the other indicator function?

Comment: The question has no answer if there is no independence assumption.

Comment: @ R. Rayl  Are you aware that convolution assumes independence?

Comment: Integral becomes $\int_0^u4x(u-x)dx$ for $0\le u\le 1$ and $\int_{u-1}^14x(u-x)dx$ for $1\le u\le 2$.